Expand product of sums in sympy by introducing new dummy indices
I want to use sympy to simplify some expressions which contain products of sums, this will require expanding out the products and cancelling equal terms.
i, j, k, l = symbols('i, j, k, l', cls=Dummy)
A = IndexedBase('A')
N = symbols('N', integer=True, positive=True)
s = Sum(A[i]*A[j], (i, 1, N), (j, 1, N))
expr = s**2

Running expr.doit(), expr.expand() or expr.simplify() will leave the expression unchanged.
The expression appears as

How can I expand the product and introduce dummy indices to turn the expression into the following?


Intresting. I don't know if you've already solved this but one way to do this is the following. First, import the required components, like you did:
from sympy import symbols, IndexedBase, Sum, Dummy, simplify

i, j, k, l = symbols('i j k l', cls=Dummy)
A = IndexedBase('A')
N = symbols('N', integer=True, positive=True)

Now,
s = Sum(A[i]*A[j], (i, 1, N), (j, 1, N))
expr = s**2

will give you the following expression
Sum(A[_i]*A[_j], (_i, 1, N), (_j, 1, N))**2

Here is how you would simplify:
expanded_expr = Sum(A[i]*A[j]*A[k]*A[l], (i, 1, N), (j, 1, N), (k, 1, N), (l, 1, N))

simplified_expr = simplify(expanded_expr)


Which will give you
Sum(A[_i]*A[_j]*A[_k]*A[_l], (_i, 1, N), (_j, 1, N), (_k, 1, N), (_l, 1, N))


